# Add shell script in cordova xcode project dynamically

Tags: ios, build-script, cordova-ios, cordova-hooks

I am planning to upload an application on app store but project contains not required architecture with it. Which cause failure in submission of app on store.

As a solution I found that I need to add a shell script which eventually remove not required architecture and allow to submit app on store.

http://ikennd.ac/blog/2015/02/stripping-unwanted-architectures-from-dynamic-libraries-in-xcode/

Now as I am creating application by automation process (not manual), is there any way in cordova/ionic to add script by creating hook or any other mechanism?

Comment: Did you found this?
https://github.com/apache/cordova-node-xcode
I think if you create a hook and use the .addBuildPhase() function you can achive what you want.
https://github.com/apache/cordova-node-xcode/blob/master/test/addBuildPhase.js (line 130)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically add build phases in Cordova based Xcode project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44371509/automatically-add-build-phases-in-cordova-based-xcode-project)